# mysql суммировать связанных таблиц

Tags: mysql

не получается правильно суммировать столбцы связанных таблиц, есть главная таблица и остальные 3 таблицы связанные с главной таблицей. главная таблица выглядит следующим образом

```
CREATE TABLE `summatable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

остальные 3 таблицы выглядит так

```
CREATE TABLE `otdel1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nameID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size3` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `otdelSwyaz` (`nameID`),
CONSTRAINT `otdelSwyaz` FOREIGN KEY (`nameID`) REFERENCES `summatable` (`id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `otdel2` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nameID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size3` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size4` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `otdelSwyaz2` (`nameID`),
CONSTRAINT `otdelSwyaz2` FOREIGN KEY (`nameID`) REFERENCES `summatable` (`id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `otdel3` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nameID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size3` int(11) NOT NULL,
`size4` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `otdelSwyaz3` (`nameID`),
 CONSTRAINT `otdelSwyaz3` FOREIGN KEY (`nameID`) REFERENCES `summatable` (`id`) ON DELETE 
 CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

мой запрос суммирование

```
SELECT summatable.name, SUM(otdel1.size1) AS 'otdel1', SUM(otdel2.size2) AS 'otdel2' FROM summatable
LEFT JOIN otdel1 ON summatable.id = otdel1.nameID 
LEFT JOIN otdel2 ON summatable.id = otdel2.nameID GROUP BY summatable.name;
```

результат такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на исходник [исходник](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e9d8f8d276e90380bb0d9e1eab731a4a)

Comment: и зачем вам эти таблицы одинаковой структуры? почему их три, а не одна?

Comment: @teran, тут для примера, самом деле основная таблица немного по другому выглядит ,  есть необходимость разделять на несколько таблиц.

Comment: каждую таблицу по отдельности получается суммировать но как объединить  результаты под общую таблицу не знаю..

Comment: через `union` например

Comment: можете как-то в примерах показать, если не трудно ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT summatable.name, SUM(otdel1.size1) AS 'size', SUM(otdel1.size2) AS
'size2', SUM(otdel1.size3) AS 'size3' from otdel1 LEFT JOIN summatable ON 
summatable.id = otdel1.nameID UNION  SELECT summatable.name, SUM(otdel2.size1) AS 
'size', SUM(otdel2.size2) AS 'size2', SUM(otdel2.size3) AS 'size3' from otdel2 
LEFT JOIN summatable ON summatable.id = otdel2.nameID UNION SELECT 
summatable.name, SUM(otdel3.size1) AS 'size', SUM(otdel3.size2) AS 'size2', 
SUM(otdel3.size3) AS 'size3' from otdel3 LEFT JOIN summatable ON summatable.id = 
otdel3.nameID;
```

благодарю! решил